# Basis of eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues of a vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

$\phi_A: sl_2\to sl_2$

Let $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ be the vector space of $2\times 2$ traceless matrices. Let $A\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ be a diagonal matrix. Define a linear operator:
$$\phi_A(X)=AX-XA$$

I want to show that $\phi_A$ is diagonalisable and find a basis of eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues.

Now traceless means that any matrix in $sl_2$ will be of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix}$$

Which means I believe the basis will be $$\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&-A\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&B\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\C&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

And an arbitrary $A$, diagonal and in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ looks like $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0\\0&-a_1\end{bmatrix}$

so we get $$\phi_A(X_1)=0$$
$$\phi_A(X_2)=\begin{bmatrix}0&2a_1 B\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\phi_A(X_3)=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-2a_1C&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: They arent eigen matrices, they are just basis matrices of $sl_2$.

Comment: The transformation $\Phi_A$ is a linear transformation, thus, it has a corresponding matrix. You can find this matrix. To find it, you must first find the basis of $sl_2$ (you already did this), then find how the basis vectors are transformed by the linear transformation.

Comment: What I meant to say was that you need to see what $\Phi_A(X)$ is for all basis vectors $X$.

Comment: No, not basis vectors *FOR* $X$, I said "all basis vectors $X$", that is: Set $X=$"first basis vector", then find out what $\Phi_A(X)$ is. Then, set $X=$"second basis bector" and find out what $\Phi_A(X)$ is. Also, read a little about what a *matrix* is. It is a *representation* of a linear operator.

Comment: @5xum Since your space is 3-dimensional, you can try to find out the matrix of the operator with respect to this basis and then the characteristic polynomial, its roots and corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: @Topology I am referring to matrices as vectors because, beside being matrices, they are also elements of a vector space (i.e. $sl_2$), meaning that they are also vectors.